# Having getopts in a seperate function in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have written the following shell script to parse arguments and print. Its not working as intended. I am sure that I am not passing correct argument to the function thats evaluating the optional params. Can some one please help is correcting it

```
#! /bin/sh

MAX_NO_OF_DATABASE=500;
MAX_NO_OF_CONCURRENT_REQUEST=500;
MAX_NO_OF_REQUEST=500;


function showUsage(){
    echo "Sample Usage : ./benchmarking.sh <CORE_URL> <SYNC_SERVER_URL> [-d MAX_NO_OF_DATABASE] [-c MAX_NO_OF_CONCURRENT_REQUEST] [-n MAX_NO_OF_REQUEST]";
    exit;
}

function readArguements(){

    # Check for core url
    if [ -z $1 ]; then
            echo "CORE_URL is not specified"
            showUsage
    fi

    # Check for sync server url
    if [ -z $2 ]; then
            echo "SYNC_SERVER_URL is not specified"
            showUsage
    fi

}
function readOptionalArguements(){

    # Check for the optional parameters
    while getopts dcn: opt
    do
            case $opt in
                    d) MAX_NO_OF_DATABASE="$OPTARG";;
                    c) MAX_NO_OF_CONCURRENT_REQUEST="$OPTARG";;
                    n) MAX_NO_OF_REQUEST="$OPTARG";;
            esac
    done
}

readArguements $*
readOptionalArguements $*
echo "$1 $2 $MAX_NO_OF_DATABASE $MAX_NO_OF_CONCURRENT_REQUEST $MAX_NO_OF_REQUEST"
```

When I run it `./benchmarker.sh core_url sync_url -d 500 -c 100 -n 200`

It prints as
`core_url sync_url 500 500 500`

I had debugging on and I could see that it does not evaluate the switch block. Am I passing the correct arguments to `readOptionalArguements`

Comment: Isn't it `getopts d:c:n: opt` ?

Comment: @PeterMmm: That didn't work

Comment: Peter is right, though.  It should be `getopts d:c:n:`.

Comment: Is this a typo `readOptionalArguement $*` ? because your function name is readOptionalArguements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the string to `d:c:n:`, because all three options take parameters.

Read carefully what `man bash` says about getopts:

> When the end of options is encountered,  getopts  exits  with  a  return
>     value  greater  than zero.  OPTIND is set to the index of the first non-
>     option argument, and name is set to ?.

Therefore, you have to process the first two non-option parameters before processing the options.

```
core_url=$1
sync_server=$2
shift 2

readArguements "$@"
readOptionalArguements "$@"
```

Also, if you are using bash, do not write `#!/bin/sh` in the shebang line.

Answer (score 2):

`getopts` **stops** on the first non-option argument, so you need to shift-out those non-option arguments before using them in `getopts`.

So for example:

```
function readOptionalArguements(){
    # skip two mandatory arguments
    shift 2
    # Check for the optional parameters
    while getopts d:c:n: opt
    do
            case $opt in
                    d) MAX_NO_OF_DATABASE="$OPTARG";;
                    c) MAX_NO_OF_CONCURRENT_REQUEST="$OPTARG";;
                    n) MAX_NO_OF_REQUEST="$OPTARG";;
            esac
    done
}
```

Also, you should declare a `local OPTIND` to keep that variable safe in case you call the function multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the problem may be in the readOptionalArguments method (btw, this is misspelled in your question). The following seems to work for me (in bash)

```
function readOptionalArguements() {
# Check for the optional parameters
while getopt "d:c:n:" $*
do
echo "opt: <$1>";
        case $1 in
                -d) shift; MAX_NO_OF_DATABASE="$1"; shift;;
                -c) shift; MAX_NO_OF_CONCURRENT_REQUEST="$1"; shift;;
                -n) shift; MAX_NO_OF_REQUEST="$1"; shift;;
        --) break;;
        *) break;;
        esac
done
```

}